# Search form for Paper_trail history using Ransack gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling to get a search form for my active record history.
I'm using the paper_trail gem as well as ransack. Both, alone, are working well. But whenever I try to implement a search form I get a strange error:

> undefined method `paper_trail_versions_path' for #<#:0x007fede31da910>

This line from my views gets highlighted:

> `<%= search_form_for @q, html: {class: "input-group"} do |f| %>`

Here's the code of the controller:

```
def history
 @all_versions = PaperTrail::Version.order('created_at DESC')
 @versions = @all_versions.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 100)
 @q = @versions.search(params[:q])
 @versions = @q.result
 respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

the views:

```
<%= search_form_for @q, html: {class: "input-group"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.search_field :whodunnit_or_item_id_cont, placeholder: "Search for Users or Actions..", class: "form-control" %>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-default") do %>
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <% end %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT resolved, thanks to answer:**

`<%= search_form_for @q, html: {class: "input-group"}, :url => "/dashboards/history/" do |f| %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error your see comes from the URL the `search_form_for` helper tries to guess for your form's action.

[Under the hood](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/master/lib/ransack/helpers/form_helper.rb#L12), Ransack uses the `polymorphic_path` rails helper, which is, [according to the doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html), a method

> for smart resolution to a named route call when given an Active Record model instance

In your case, your model is a `PaperTrail::Version`, which resolves to `paper_trail_versions_path`.

To fix the error, you can either :

- define the corresponding resource in your `routes.rb` file, so that the helper is defined
- manually define the helper
- provide to the search form a `url` option, with the path to your form's action.

Hope it helps!